# what does the PIC18 compile error 195 mean?

Tags: syntax, compiler-errors, pic, microchip, pic18

I'm relatively new to programming PIC18 micro-controllers and I keep getting a compile error 195 when I try to get my code to compile. The PIC I'm using is a PIC18F46k80, and the application I'm trying to program it for is for a piece of hardware with the PIC already embedded, so I can't change the Pin configuration (I didn't design the hardware). I'm trying to get my PIC to perform a slightly modified SPI protocol via bit-banging as the correct pins for the internal peripheral haven't been connect. I keep running into this compile error whenever I try to set RA6 or RA5, even though (I think) I've configured the pins to make them writable (not providing the internal clock). Specifically I get the error when trying to set LATA6 = x or LATA5 = x. In MPLAB X every issue of me writing LATA6 or LATA5 is highlighted. Can someone help me with writing/setting these pins?
Any instance of the follow code will cause an issue:

```
    LATA5 = 0;
    //or
    LAT6 = 0;
    //or
    LAT6 = 1;
```

I can send through the entire file including headers and config files if needed :) Cheers for any help.

Here is the entire code:

```
#include "mcc_generated_files/mcc.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<xc.h>


//Define words for transfer//
uint8_t FR1IByte = 0x01;
int FR1DBytes = 0x900000;

uint8_t CSRIByte = 0x00;
uint8_t CSRCH0 = 0x10;
uint8_t CSRCH1 = 0x20;
uint8_t CSRCH2 = 0x40;

uint8_t CFTWIByte = 0x04;
uint32_t CFTWCH0 = 0x42680000;
uint32_t CFTWCH1 = 0x1F400000;
uint32_t CFTWCH2 = 0x3E800000;


//Functions to perform SPI//
void SPItransfer8( uint8_t byte)
{

    // local variable declaration
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i <8; i++){ //compares MSB with mask. If it matches, it will transfer a 1//
        if(byte & 0x80)
        {
            LATC5 = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            LATC5 = 0;
        }

        // Pulses clock for transfer of data//
        LATA6 = 1;
        LATA6 = 0;

        // Logical shift left so that next byte can be read//
        byte <<= 1;
     }
}

void SPItransfer24( int bytes)
{
    // local variable declaration
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i <24; i++);
    {   //compares MSB with mask. If it matches, it will transfer a 1//
        if(bytes & 0x800000) 
        {
            LATC5 = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            LATC5 = 0;
         }
         // Pulses clock for transfer of data//
         LATA6 = 1;
         LATA6 = 0;

        // Logical shift left so that next byte can be read//
        bytes <<= 1;
    }
}

void SPItransfer32( uint32_t bytes)
{
    // local variable declaration
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i <32; i++);
    {   //compares MSB with mask. If it matches, it will transfer a 1//
        if(bytes & 0x80000000)
        {
            LATC5 = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            LATC5 = 0;
        }

        // Pulses clock for transfer of data//
        LATA6 = 1;
        LATA6 = 0;

        // Logical shift left so that next byte can be read//
        bytes <<= 1;
    }
}

void main(void)
{
    TRISE = 0x03;
    TRISA = 0b1001111;

 // Initialize the device//
    SYSTEM_Initialize();
    // Perform master reset on DDS to set the device to its default state (Active high on E2)//
    LATE1 = 1;
    LATE1 = 0;
    // Delay to allow the system to load (PLL takes time to lock) //
    __delay_ms(10)


    //Set RA5 to low to prevent power down//
    LATA5 = 0;

    //Set RA6 to low for SPI clock//
    LATA6 = 0;

    //Transfers the Function Register 1 Information Byte//
    SPItransfer8(FR1IByte);

    //Transfers the Function Register 1 Data Bytes//
    SPItransfer24(FR1DBytes);

    //Transfers the Channel Select Register Information Byte//
    SPItransfer8(CSRIByte);

    //Transfers the Channel Select Register Data Byte for CH0
    SPItransfer8(CSRCH0);

    //Transfers the Channel Frequency Tuning Word Information Byte//
    SPItransfer8(CFTWIByte);

    //Transfers the Channel 0 Frequency Tuning Word//
    SPItransfer32(CFTWCH0);

    //Transfers the Channel Select Register Information Byte//
    SPItransfer8(CSRIByte);

    //Transfers the Channel Select Register Data Byte for CH1
    SPItransfer8(CSRCH1);

    //Transfers the Channel Frequency Tuning Word Information Byte//
    SPItransfer8(CFTWIByte);

    //Transfers the Channel 1 Frequency Tuning Word//
    SPItransfer32(CFTWCH1);

    //Transfers the Channel Select Register Information Byte//
    SPItransfer8(CSRIByte);

    //Transfers the Channel Select Register Data Byte for CH2
    SPItransfer8(CSRCH2);

    //Transfers the Channel Frequency Tuning Word Information Byte//
    SPItransfer8(CFTWIByte);

    //Transfers the Channel 2 Frequency Tuning Word//
    SPItransfer32(CFTWCH2);

//Toggle I/O_Update to load data into DDS//
PORTEbits.RE2 = 1;
PORTEbits.RE2 = 0;

//Loop holding RA6 low to prevent further data transmission//
    while (1)
    {
         PORTAbits.RA6 = 0;
    }
}
```

Here are the MCC generated config files:

```
// CONFIG1L
#pragma config RETEN = OFF    // VREG Sleep Enable bit->Ultra low-power regulator is Disabled (Controlled by REGSLP bit)
#pragma config INTOSCSEL = HIGH    // LF-INTOSC Low-power Enable bit->LF-INTOSC in High-power mode during Sleep
#pragma config SOSCSEL = DIG    // SOSC Power Selection and mode Configuration bits->Digital (SCLKI) mode
#pragma config XINST = OFF    // Extended Instruction Set->Disabled

// CONFIG1H
#pragma config FOSC = INTIO2    // Oscillator->Internal RC oscillator
#pragma config PLLCFG = OFF    // PLL x4 Enable bit->Disabled
#pragma config FCMEN = OFF    // Fail-Safe Clock Monitor->Disabled
#pragma config IESO = OFF    // Internal External Oscillator Switch Over Mode->Disabled

// CONFIG2L
#pragma config PWRTEN = OFF    // Power Up Timer->Disabled
#pragma config BOREN = SBORDIS    // Brown Out Detect->Enabled in hardware, SBOREN disabled
#pragma config BORV = 3    // Brown-out Reset Voltage bits->1.8V
#pragma config BORPWR = ZPBORMV    // BORMV Power level->ZPBORMV instead of BORMV is selected

// CONFIG2H
#pragma config WDTEN = OFF    // Watchdog Timer->WDT disabled in hardware; SWDTEN bit disabled
#pragma config WDTPS = 1048576    // Watchdog Postscaler->1:1048576

// CONFIG3H
#pragma config CANMX = PORTB    // ECAN Mux bit->ECAN TX and RX pins are located on RB2 and RB3, respectively
#pragma config MSSPMSK = MSK7    // MSSP address masking->7 Bit address masking mode
#pragma config MCLRE = OFF    // Master Clear Enable->MCLR Disabled, RE3 Enabled

// CONFIG4L
#pragma config STVREN = ON    // Stack Overflow Reset->Enabled
#pragma config BBSIZ = BB2K    // Boot Block Size->2K word Boot Block size

// CONFIG5L
#pragma config CP0 = OFF    // Code Protect 00800-03FFF->Disabled
#pragma config CP1 = OFF    // Code Protect 04000-07FFF->Disabled
#pragma config CP2 = OFF    // Code Protect 08000-0BFFF->Disabled
#pragma config CP3 = OFF    // Code Protect 0C000-0FFFF->Disabled

// CONFIG5H
#pragma config CPB = OFF    // Code Protect Boot->Disabled
#pragma config CPD = OFF    // Data EE Read Protect->Disabled

// CONFIG6L
#pragma config WRT0 = OFF    // Table Write Protect 00800-03FFF->Disabled
#pragma config WRT1 = OFF    // Table Write Protect 04000-07FFF->Disabled
#pragma config WRT2 = OFF    // Table Write Protect 08000-0BFFF->Disabled
#pragma config WRT3 = OFF    // Table Write Protect 0C000-0FFFF->Disabled

// CONFIG6H
#pragma config WRTC = OFF    // Config. Write Protect->Disabled
#pragma config WRTB = OFF    // Table Write Protect Boot->Disabled
#pragma config WRTD = OFF    // Data EE Write Protect->Disabled

// CONFIG7L
#pragma config EBTR0 = OFF    // Table Read Protect 00800-03FFF->Disabled
#pragma config EBTR1 = OFF    // Table Read Protect 04000-07FFF->Disabled
#pragma config EBTR2 = OFF    // Table Read Protect 08000-0BFFF->Disabled
#pragma config EBTR3 = OFF    // Table Read Protect 0C000-0FFFF->Disabled

// CONFIG7H
#pragma config EBTRB = OFF    // Table Read Protect Boot->Disabled
```

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: Errror 195 told you there was a problem with your syntax. Have you included xc.h?

Comment: I've updated the post with the config files and the entire code attached. Cheers for any help :)

Comment: Try:  `LATAbits.RA5=0;` instead `LATA5 = 0;`

Comment: Tried:
    LATAbits.RA5 = 0;
and unfortunately it still doesn't work. I've also tried playing around with the ANCON Register (manually setting all the ANSEL bits to digital), and it still won't compile.

Comment: What happens if you press[CTRL] and click on LATA5? If everything works fine with xc.h MPLABX should direct you to the PIC header file with the definition of LATA5.

Comment: It's not causing your error but `int FR1DBytes = 0x900000;` will overflow. The max size of an int for this processor is 32767 (see limits.h). Changing to unsigned long would fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is actually in the line just above `LATA5 = 0;`. The macro `__delay_ms` is defined in pic18.h as:

`_delay((unsigned long)((x)*(_XTAL_FREQ/4000000.0)))`

and requires a statement terminator. You are missing a semicolon. Change the line to:

```
__delay_ms(10);
```